# Mysterious behavior from DATEADD in WHERE clause of a stored procedure 

Tags: sql, performance, datetime, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

Here is the problem I am having. A table that I am querying has 170 million rows. I wrote a stored procedure to do a simple query about the latest entries into the table. When I write the `WHERE` clause with a hard-coded string like this:

```
SELECT top 500 a.field1 , a.field2, a.field3
FROM database..hugeTable a( nolock )
WHERE a.StartTime > '2012-07-17 10:10:35.477'
```

it is very fast. Less than a second. `StartTime` is in a non-clustered index.

However, what I really want is this:

```
DECLARE @fifteenMinutesAgo datetime;
SET @fifteenMinutesAgo = DATEADD(n , -15 , GETDATE());

SELECT top 500 a.field1 , a.field2, a.field3
FROM database..hugeTable a( nolock )
WHERE a.StartTime > @fifteenMinutesAgo
```

The problem is that when I run the second query, it takes almost 3 minutes!

So I started messing around and searching like crazy. I thought that it might be a datatype problem so I tried various CASTs and CONVERTs and had no success. I tried using `OPTIMIZE FOR` but realized it would not work on this version of SQL. I checked the datatype of `StartTime`; it is of type `datetime`.

Another thing that I tried, which was very weird, was this:

```
DECLARE @fifteenDaysAgo datetime;
SET @fifteenDaysAgo = DATEADD(d , -15 , GETDATE());

SELECT top 500 a.field1 , a.field2, a.field3
FROM database..hugeTable a( nolock )
WHERE a.StartTime > @fifteenDaysAgo
```

I changed it from searching for the last 15 minutes, to the last 15 days. Magically it was super-fast again! Less than a second.

This lead me to believe that somehow it is hard for SQL to compare time? It didn't need to look at the `TIME` portion of the `datetime` to see if it fit the compare statement? I don't know. Here I am grasping at straws.

So my question is, how can I make this reasonably fast and still keep my `@fifteenMinutesAgo` dynamic?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan between the two queries to see what the possible differences in execution are?

Comment: I should have included that. Yes, the execution plans are identical.

Comment: Can you try executing the slow version of stored procedure `WITH RECOMPILE` option and see if it helps ?

Comment: a1ex07, you hit it. It is automagically fast now.   Please add an answer.  In the mean time, I'll be researching the performance impact on that `RECOMPILE` statement.

Comment: Are you actually using *variables* as your example code would indicate or parameters?

Comment: I may have jumped the gun here.  I **swear** that when I added the `WITH RECOMPILE` statement it ran fast.  I ran it three times and it took less than a second.  But now . . . it's slow again.  After looking at the linked article, it doesn't make sense that `WITH RECOMPILE` should help.  I am in fact just using variables in the SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have "[parameter sniffing](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/)" problem with your procedure. `WITH RECOMPILE` option should help

Comment: As I said in the comments to the question, I really thought that this was the problem. But, since reading the article that you linked to, I realized that it is not the problem.  I'm not using parameters, I'm using variables.  BUT, somehow, adding the `WITH RECOMPILE` to my SP made it fast for a while.  I just CTRL-Z'd my way back through my exact steps to be sure that I ran it properly and that I didn't somehow leave the hard-coded date in there when testing your suggestion.  Any other ideas?

Comment: If it does help from time to time, I'd suspect that stats is not updated properly, and optimizer uses wrong execution plan. I'm not familiar with SQLServer 2000; in 2005 and 2008 you can force the query to use a particular execution plan, not sure if there is such an option in 2000...

Comment: Another suggestion: if you are using conditions in the body of stored procedure, there is also a chance you have the problem very similar to parameter sniffing - procedure compiled and execution plan created when you execute it first time, then it reuses the same plan.

Comment: I ended up spending way too much time on this problem, so I ended up with a work-around.  I was initially looking for the data inserted into this massive table in the past 15 minutes, I knew that there were never more than a couple thousand records entered in that time, so I just queried the bottom 10,000 records and then ran an 'outer' query on those, filtering by date.  The time is back down to sub-second.  I'll have to say I learned a bunch of stuff about 'parameter sniffing' though.  Thanks for your time.